# Repeating "sqlite3.DatabaseError sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is not a database"

Tags: database, sqlite

attempting to use the following sqlite3 database with a python server on pycharm, however I keep running into a database.error

sqlite3 script:
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] user_prompts (
column_1 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
column_2 gender TEXT,
column_3 name TEXT
)
''')

conn.commit()
conn.close()

Attempted to place it into an online SQLite viewer (https://inloop.github.io/sqlite-viewer/) but again got the same error from the website.

Comment: Sounds like database.sqlite is not a sqlite3 database, but some other file format.

Comment: Oh and your create table systax is wrong. See https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html